# Excel background colour changing automatically

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Whenever I copy or move a cell in excel, the original cell location changes colour, how can I stop this?

[image]

I have tried clearing the format but it doesn't seem to help... and it only occurs in the main area that I am working in (i.e. if I scroll off to the side or bottom it doesn't seem to happen).

Anyone have any ideas? It's quite annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional Formatting should do the trick. Highlight the cells that concern you and use the option if Cell contains value... then select blank. The format should be auto background (or whatever color you would like)

You may find a custom format already there causing the issue. If so just delete it and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, good way to fix it. Although you would think that you shouldn't have to fix something like that...